# .htaccess multiple rewritecond not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

On my webserver I have an imagefolder which I want to protect from direct linking. I know there are several methods to do this, but I also want to put up two RewriteCond's in `.htaccess` that do this:

- If the request_URI contains the word 'output' (this is the imagefolder), the standard reaction would be to block this request

**UNLESS:**

- the user sends an header on request called 'testheader', which can be empty

This way, people that try to directlink or download will get an error, unless they send the header. I know this can be easily done, it's just creating another barrier to overcome.

My `.htaccess` looks like this:

```
RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" ".*output.*"
RewriteCond "{%HTTP:testheader}" "!^$"
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Can't figure out why this doesn't work. If I only use the first RewriteCond and comment out the second it does work.

To test if it works I'm loading the images through an xhr request in JavaScript. This way:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.responseType = 'blob'; //so you can access the response like a normal URL
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status == 200) {
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response); //create <img> with src set to the blob
        document.body.appendChild(img);
    }
};
xhr.open('GET', 'https://www.example.com/output/test.png', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('testheader', '');
xhr.send();
```

Comment: Have you verified the client you are testing this with actually correctly sends this header?

Comment: FYI, there is no need to use a RewriteCond, only to check on the URL path - the RewriteRule itself can do that perfectly fine on its own already. `RewriteRule output - [F]`

Comment: @CBroe Yes the client sends this header, I have checked this with Chrome/Firefox Deleveloper tools

Comment: Try `RewriteCond {%HTTP:testheader} .*` - you just want it to be set, the value to be anything, even empty - which `.*` matches perfectly fine.

Comment: @CBroe I basically need to need both conditions to be true, it needs output in its name AND the request should not have a header named 'testheader'. Am I able to combine this condition with the RewriteRule you are suggesting? My mistake is maybe to test if the second statement is NOT true?

Comment: The _path_ condition (because RewriteRule can match against _that_); you will still need to use a RewriteCond for the header.

Comment: @CBroe But the header condition should only be checked if the path condition is true. If I check against the header condition first, everything is blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Putting a `.htaccess` with the following content in the `/output/` directory, will do what I want to do. I also now test whether the content of the header is containing 'tst' as a string:

````
RewriteCond "%{HTTP:testheader}" !tst
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```
````